# IOS app is not working on different different internet connections

Tags: ios, react-native

I have created react-native app for IOS. I have installed it on different different iPhones. It works fine. If I change my WiFi (named ABC) to another network (named DEF) on my mac and then upload it again on my mobile then it will crash. My Mac and my mobile WiFi network is the same. I have also tested it on mobile data and it's not working. But if I connect to WiFi (named ABC) and same on mobile then it works properly. It works only with one network. Why its not working with another WiFi netoworks and also with mobile data?

Comment: Which server are you connecting to? Is the server available in both networks. Please post the error logs

Comment: Maybe you changed your network from ABC to DEF after build, Right? You should change your network first and after that build again (run `react-native run-ios`)